# Replace String using Sed?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am new to Unix and Linux and am trying to replace a certain strings in a file using `sed`.

This is what I have so far:

```
Param1=CHANGEME 
Param2=Value2 
Param3=CHANGEME 
Param4=Value4
```

If I do this command :-  `sed -i 's/CHANGEME/VALUE/g' input.txt`, "CHANGEME" will be replaced by the text "VALUE" which is fine.

What if I want to change "Value" with it's corresponding value number so essentially for Param1=Value1 and for Param3=Value3 ?

How can I achieve that? Thank you

Comment: Use a capture group to get the number at the end of `Param`, and then use a back-reference in the replacement text.

Comment: If these lines are 1 and 3, use `sed -i  '1 s/CHANGEME/VALUE1/; 3 s/CHANGEME/VALUE3/' file`. Also, `sed -i -E 's/^(Param1)=.*/\1VALUE1/; s/^(Param3)=.*/\1VALUE3/' file` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU sed ...

Your snippet saved to `hugger`:

```
cat hugger 
Param1=CHANGEME 
Param2=value2 
Param3=CHANGEME 
Param4=value
```

The following `sed` command does what you want, I think:

```
sed -r '/CHANGEME/s/Param([0-9]+)=.*/Param\1=Value\1/' hugger 
Param1=Value1
Param2=value2 
Param3=Value3
Param4=value4
```